# How to format a string in bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to format a variable in linux

```
str="Initial Value = 168" 
echo "New Value=$(echo $str|  cut -d '=' -f2);">>test.txt
```

I am expecting the following output

```
Value = 168;
```

But instead get

```
Value = 168 ^M;
```

Comment: What's your input? please separate the input and command.

Comment: For mor complex formatting, try `printf` shell command. (And that ^M is CR, so you have some odd line break there.)

Comment: My input string value is "Initial Value = 168 "

Comment: Could it be that your input string had a CR+LF instead of LF only? If your snippet is in a file, your editor may be using wrong line breaks. In that case the string "...168<CR><LF>" is interpreted as a text which ends with <CR> in the end.

Comment: I am trying format before echo to the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't edit your bash script on DOS or Windows. You can run `dos2unix` on the bash script. The issue is that Windows uses "\r\n" as a line separator, Linux uses "\n". You can also manually remove the "\r" characters in an editor on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

```
str="Initial Value = 168"
newstr="${str##* }"
echo "$newstr"  # 168
```

pattern matching is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash

str="Initial Value = 168"

awk '{print $2"="$4}' <<< $str > test.txt
```

Output:

```
cat test.txt
Value=168
```

I've got comment saying that it doesn't address ^M, I actually does:

```
echo -e 'Initial Value = 168 \r' | cat -A 
Initial Value = 168 ^M$
```

After `awk`:

```
echo -e 'Initial Value = 168 \r' | awk '{print $2"="$4}' | cat -A
Value=168$
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, always quote your variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

str="Initial Value = 168"
echo "New Value=$(echo "$str" | cut -d '=' -f2);"
```

For me, this results in the output:

```
New Value= 168;
```

If you're getting a carriage return between the digits and the semicolon, then something may be wrong with your `echo`, or perhaps your input data is not what you think it is.  Perhaps you're editing your script on a Windows machine and copying it back, and your variable assignment is getting DOS-style newlines.  From the information you've provided in your question, I can't tell.

At any rate I wouldn't do things this way.  I'd use `printf`.

```
#!/bin/bash

str="Initial Value = 168"
value=${str##*=}
printf "New Value=%d;\n" "$value"
```

The output of `printf` is predictable, and it handily strips off gunk like whitespace when you don't want it.

Note the replacement of your `cut`.  The functionality of bash built-ins is documented in the Bash man page under "Parameter Expansion", if you want to look it up.  The replacement I've included here is not *precisely* the same functionality as what you've got in your question, but is functionally equivalent for the sample data you've provided.

Comment: Recommending `echo | cut` rather than bash builtins (such as parameter expansion or read) is somewhat unfortunate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - fixed.  Wanted to get the answer in, then clean it up. :)